# Recipe for baking bread/cake on the trail

Tags: hiking, cooking

I cooked a couple of times but I was just aiding a colleague that also brought all the ingredients and had the know-how. And I have a poor memory, obviously.

How do you cook yours? What recipe do you use? Details are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get the recipe from an experienced hiking friend that I think is closer to what I'm looking for:

> Flour, baking powder. for the amount of baking powder basically follow the advice on the baking powder, I don't and just do it by "feeling"; exact amount isn't critical.
>   Sugar & Salt to taste. Bit of oil. 
>   That's it. 
>   On the trail, you just add water & knead thoroughly, and let it sit for at least half an hour before baking.
>   Then bake slowly (= low heat) in a pan or a pot w/ a little bit of oil.
>
> You can throw in whatever you want basically, i. e. raisins or chocolate bits.
>   You can use full wheat flour (also has more energy then the white flour).
>   The kind of oil doesn't really mater, I used olive.
>   Sunflower or canola are good choices for mostly taste-neutral oil.

Comment: i will surely try this next time I am up in the hills!

Answer (score 5):

Here are two dessert recipes I like to make while camping:

#### Peach Cobbler:

- 1 (big/commercial-sized) can of peaches in heavy syrup
- 1 (regular-sized) box of cake mix (plain yellow cake, unless you want to get adventurous).

Heat up some coals, pour the peaches into a dutch oven, and pour the cake mix evenly over the peaches. Put the top on the dutch oven (including coals on top), bake until it's done: The peach syrup should bubble over into the cake mix over much of it, the rest of the cake mix should be just starting to brown. How long depends a lot on your fire/coals.

If you're hiking and a dutch oven is too much, you can probably get away with putting it in a fairly wide pan on a camp stove.

You can also experiment with other fruits and cake mix flavors; but note that the heavy syrup is important, it keeps the syrup below the cake mix in a place to bubble up properly.

#### Pound cake

- 1 pound butter
- 1 pound sugar
- 1 pound flour
- 1 pound eggs

Melt the butter in a dutch oven. Pour in the sugar, mix quickly, flour, mix quickly, eggs, mix quickly and then thoroughly. Put the lid on, bake until it's done.

I imagine this doesn't translate to a camp stove quite as well as the peach cobbler, but if you have a pot that can handle the temperature and you don't mind getting it dirty (and possibly melting, if you misjudged its sturdiness) you can try putting it in a pit surrounded (beyond a bit of a gap) by coals piled up.

Also, this one can obviously be scaled down to smaller portions (e.g. 1/4 lb of each) if you are in a smaller party.

Comment: I don't think I can do this while hiking (too heavy, can't have fresh food etc.), but thanks for the recipes.